# vb.net polling Sql server once a second causing timeout

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, vb.net-2010

I was asked to do a system that would poll one table in the database every second and if it counters a row that meets a criteria start actions to handle that.

I've done this but every now and then I get a time out exception. I have a WPF application where I have a thread that runs in background. This thread has a loop and sleeps for one second at the end of the loop. The connection to the database is opened inside "using" clause.

Below is my thread sub:

```
Private Sub PollDatabase()
    While m_StopThread = False
      Try
        Dim listOfRows As List(Of DataObject) = db.GetDataObjects()

        ... Do something with the rows ...

       Catch ex As Exception
          m_log.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
       End Try
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

And my SQL function looks like this:

```
Public Function GetDataObjects() As List(Of DataObject)
  Dim result As New List(Of DataObject)
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder("... the sql query ...")

     Using cnn = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)
         cnn.Open()
         Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), cnn)
          cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
          Using DataReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While DataReader.Read()
              ... read the columns from table 
                  to the dataobject ...
              result.Add(DataObject)
            Loop
          End Using
        End Using
     End Using
  Return result
End Function
```

Now what seems randomly my log has a time out exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
...
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

My questions are: is this at all save way of doing this? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? And of course if anyone have a suggestion to fix this issue.

EDIT:

I tried a bit different approach with the SQL function. I'm now opening a connection once when my application starts and dumped the "using" clauses. So my function looks something like this now:

```
Public Function GetDataObjects() As List(Of DataObject)
  Dim result As New List(Of DataObject)
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder("... the sql query ...")
  _sqlCmd.CommandText = sb.ToString()

  Using DataReader As SqlDataReader = _sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
      Do While DataReader.Read()
         ... fill the list with objects ...
      Loop
  End Using

  Return result
End Function
```

My log is clean form errors. So is there something wrong opening a connection to the server once in a second as I do with the using?

EDIT:

I've done a lot of testing now to identify the problem. What I discovered is that just connecting multiple times to the server doesn't cause any problems. Neither does adding a select statement after the connection. But when I actually implement a function where is the complete reader part and return my results I run into the time out problems. Here is two examples.

This isn't causing issues:

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.DataContext = Me
    m_Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionTestFunction)
    m_Thread.IsBackground = True
    m_Thread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ConnectionTestFunction()
    While m_stopThread = False
        Try
            m_log.WriteLine("GetData (" & m_ThreadCounter & ")")
            Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
                cnn.Open()
                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Data", cnn)
                    Using DataReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        Do While DataReader.Read()
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            m_log.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        m_ThreadCounter += 1
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

This is causing timeout errors:

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.DataContext = Me
    m_Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionTestFunction)
    m_Thread.IsBackground = True
    m_Thread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ConnectionTestFunction()
    While m_stopThread = False
        Try
            m_log.WriteLine("GetData (" & m_ThreadCounter & ")")
            Dim datarows As List(Of Data) = Me.GetData()
        Catch ex As Exception
            m_log.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        m_ThreadCounter += 1
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub

Private Function GetData() As List(Of Data)
    Dim result As New List(Of Data)
    Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
        cnn.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Data", cnn)
            Using DataReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Do While DataReader.Read()
                    Dim d As New Data()
                    d.DataId = DataReader("DataId")
                    ... etc fields about 10 of them ...
                    result.Add(d)
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

I'm really happy if anyone have any thoughts about this... I have to admit I'm really confused now.

Comment: Have you looked in the SQL log? Is your server just busy? Do you have Exchange installed on the same box?

Comment: Hey Peter, no I don't have Exchange. The server isn't in very heavy use. It is used internally by five ppl or so.

Comment: Hmm.. something is happening on the server. There is a Chinese IP address trying to connect with sa -account more than once a second according to the log. I'm guessing this could cause some lag? I'm not in anyway a SQL server or network professional.

Comment: It may not be relevant - assuming they are just *trying* to get in, rather than succeeding. IME if you have a SQL Server exposed on the internet (best avoided if poss, but not always poss) then it will inevitably be the target of attacks like this. At the very least, delete the sa account and if you can, restrict access to a known range of ip addresses; hide it any way you can. They're not targeting you - they're just walking around trying door handles.  There's nothing wrong, *in your situation* with opening one connection and keeping it open.

Comment: Edited my question to show two blocks of code that I've used to test the server to find out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Have a look at the Activity monitor in SSMS and the Performance monitor on the server

Comment: My query is shown on the resent expensive queries list, but don't know exactly what I should look at :) Also I noticed that the memory seems low in the server performance monitor. The "Free" value is between 0 and 4 and SqlServer looks to be using 1,3Gb of memory. Is there something special I should be paying attention to?

Comment: You should be using those tools to find out what is happening on the server *when the query fails*.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a server problem. I used my dev-db in my laptop from the machine where I get the timeouts with my app and no time outs so far with a 1000 pollings (with our main sql server there would have been timeouts according to my previous tests). I'll run the app for a while longer to see if that is in fact the case but looks like it is some issue on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your code is taking longer to complete than the default time-out value for the connection is. Try specifying the time-out when you create your Sql Connection. Make sure that it's longer than the time your code needs to complete.

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't seem very good.. Instead of pooling, why not react when new data comes? You can use a trigger or SqlDependency?

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Comment: Heya, I can't do anything on the SQL Server. I can't add triggers, procedures, etc.. But I can do what ever with my vb.net code. I'll take a look at the SqlDepency that's a new subject for me.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like SqlDepency is out of question too :(. It may be a very good solution and looks like something that should be used but my boss says as we have similar code elsewhere we should do this the same way and figure out why I'm getting error with the "using" clause and not with opening only one connection rather than trying to go around the problem. So my question remains that is it wrong to open a new connection every time you need to commit some sql?